# help about converting PSD to HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I am familiar with CSS and HTML and also I saw some tutorials about converting PSD to HTML / CSS.
like [this](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/1-converting-a-photoshop-mockup-part-1-of-3/).
Now I have a PSD template that I want to convert it to an HTML/CSS page.
Its picture of mentioned template [image]
Now I am confused.I don't know where to slice and convert to PNG images.

- For example Top black 404 , Should I
  convert it to PNG Image and putting
  on website ?
- Or I have to write it self with same
  font? Also about the Text error that
  placed under top page 404.
- Should I slice and Save background as
  picture and putting it on the
  background of page?

please share your experiences.

Comment: You can probably have some luck with http://www.google.com/webfonts. I mean for using fonts instead of images

Comment: I wonder about down vote withount any description ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no sense in doing a background image AND a png for the header if you can do both of them in the same image, I think. That will save response time for your 404.

That said, I would recommend taking all the text off below "404 error" to save the background image and then positioning the white text with css positioning and a standard font.

Also, you'll need to cut out the search box to make that the background of your search input field and the search button for the background of your button div or button input, whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you.
Do you have any idea about creating Textbox like template using css and Images ? (tutorial link or something else.)

Comment: You would use `<input type="text" id="search-box" />` for your textbox and simply use css to give your text box the appropriate background and padding. The only thing I'm not sure you can control with css would be the width, so you'd have to experiment with that.

See:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/text-input-single/
http://www.tdl.com/~jrb/jrb7/css_textfield0.html

Comment: Thank you again. 
as my background is image and its not color will i have some problems on browser resize?  do you have any recommendation about that ?

Comment: Shaahin, your image doesn't look too large, so it should be fine. If it is worrying you, do some tests with your browser at different window sizes and see how gracefully it decays, it may be that a few adjustments to your CSS may be necessary to keep the architecture. But if I had to guess, I would say it is pretty safe is.

Answer (score 3):

I would just add text as text using @fontface

With the following website you can convert your font for the web and it even creates the CSS for you I think.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

However you need to have a license to use the font on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first start by reconsidering using a large background image that a) makes the type hard to read and b) is going to take longer to download for a 404 message page.

If you stick with it, you will obviously want one background image of the paper.

I'd convert your '404 error' text into a png and then use it as the background image of an h1 tag using an image replacement technique to retain the text in the markup. Alternately, you could use it as an IMG with appropriate ALT attribute.

Comment: @Da Thank you.
As my background is image and its not Color , I think I'll have some trouble on browser resize because I should put image as PNG or GIF on background.
Do you have any recomendation ?